# How to remove Linux Mint Logo for my Desktop

Tags: linux-mint

[image]

[image]
I am running Linux mint 19.2 64-bit how to solve this problem

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve the problem?

Comment: search google and linux mint forum but not any related answer

Comment: Would just changing the desktop backgound solve this?

Comment: desktop background change but not remove water mark logo

Comment: Is the watermark a [screenlet](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-linux-mint-after-installation-mint-17-cinnamon-edition.htm)?

Comment: The [watermark](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/46) is a [Cinnamon Spice](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in "Settings > Extensions" and clicking on "Disable Watermark".